# How to include milliseconds into DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this property I am using to set the Time Stamp from a database.

```
string format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff";
  /// <summary>
  /// Gets the DateTime data and converts it to UTC
  /// </summary>
  public DateTime TimeStamp
  {
    get
    {
      return _TimeStamp.ToLocalTime();
    }
    set
    {
      if (_TimeStamp != null)
      {
        _TimeStamp = value;
      }        
    }
  }
```

How i am getting things from my databse is as follows:

```
using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
        {
          con.Open();

          string stm = @"Select * From Messages m join MessageDetails md on m.MessageID = md.MessageID GROUP BY m.MessageID";

          using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(stm, con))
          {
            using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
              while (rdr.Read())
              {
                MessageDetails detail = new MessageDetails { MessageID = rdr.GetString(0), TimeStamp = rdr.GetDateTime(1), StoreNumber = rdr.GetString(2), TerminalNumber = rdr.GetInt32(3) };

                ViewModel.MetricsResult.Add(detail);
              }
            }
          }
```

This part is from another class.

The database spits out the time stamp including Day of the week, day, 4 digit year, then it shows Hours(hh), minutes (mm) and seconds (ss). But I would like to include the milliseconds as well.

Would I have to convert my DateTime to string? Or is there a way to do so and still keep everything as DateTime?

What would I have to do inside this property in order to display my DateTime with Milliseconds? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like the problem has nothing to do with the code you've shown us, and everything to do with how you're fetching it from the database - which you haven't shown us. (I'd personally advise against converting to local time, particularly as you only appear to do that in one direction, but that's a different matter.) Please clarify your question.

Comment: You need to clarify your question. But to answer some portions, `DateTime` structure can store at a granularity of a [`Tick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) which is equal to 100 nano-seconds. To Display the milli seconds you can use [custom time format fff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-fff-custom-format-specifier). And as Jon pointed out, your problem also involves storing the DateTime in DB and transporting it back and forth between the C# App and the DB

Answer (score -2):

use three "f"
string format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff";

Comment: Why do he need to use exactly three `f` signs? Or how does it even refer to the question itself?

Comment: @m.rogalski because it would be centiseconds, not milliseconds, otherwise

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I was expecting to see some update on answer to have some details rather than a comment.